# Media Player not playing sound properly in Android on charger connection

Tags: java, android, audio-player

I am new to software developing and i am trying to make an application that will play a sound when it charges. The first time i connect it to the charging cable, it plays the sound two times, which is not expected. Also, when i connect and disconnect the cable too quick, it also plays it twice.
Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

```
package com.mccharginggimmick;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

IntentFilter intentFilter;
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayerOff;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayerOn;
boolean playedOnceOn;
boolean playedOnceOff;
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

            if(isCharging){
            onCharge();
            }
            else{
            onDisconnect();
            }
        }
    };
    MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
public void onCharge(){

    if(!playedOnceOn){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mediaPlayerOn = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.btnon);
    mediaPlayerOn.start();
    mediaPlayerOn.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayerOn.stop();
            playedOnceOn = true;
            playedOnceOff = false;
        }
    });
    }
}
public void onDisconnect(){

    if(!playedOnceOff){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mediaPlayerOff = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.btnoff);
    mediaPlayerOff.start();
    mediaPlayerOff.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayerOff.stop();
            playedOnceOff = true;
            playedOnceOn = false;
        }
    });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you are not very clear, do you want to make sound on cable connected and another sound on charge full or just one time sound at charge full?

Answer (score 0):

define `isCabelConnected` inside class

```
boolean isCabelConnected = false;
```

then in your `onClick`

```
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
            boolean isFullCharged = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

            if(isCharging && !isCabelConnected){
            onCharge();
            isCabelConnected = true;
            } else if (isFullCharged && isCabelConnected){
            onCharge();
            }
            else{
            onDisconnect();
            isCabelConnected = false;
            }
```

this code will make a sound when cable connected and another sound when full charge